# How do you use a strong attack with a PC keyboard in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm playing the [Patch 1.12](http://thewitcher.com/news/view/1192) version of Witcher 3 on PC using Windows 7 and an English input keyboard.

I'm having problems executing strong attacks with the default keyboard controls, specifically

<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd>

It works outside of combat, but as soon as I'm in combat, holding down Shift and clicking the left mouse button no longer works, Geralt just stands around doing nothing.

**Is this a bug? Or am I not executing strong attacks correctly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Cant strong attack, left shift and left mouse dont work](http://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/617335934150355203/#c613958868351993450), holding down shift and **double-clicking** the left mouse button (instead of a single click) will make you execute a strong attack:

> You have to make shift+double click. At least for me that works.

I've found this to work in combat, **but inconsistently**, as noted by someone else in the next post to that thread:

> Only sometimes. Something is wrong with the keyboardinput.

Answer (score 2):

On PC strong attack has it's separate binding and after some updates it might be reset to None. You can bind it to any key in the keys settings.

Update: I have played the latest patched game, and strong attack is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd>